# Python 2.7: Determining the length when using next with a python Iterator

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am performing the following extraction and it is working:

```
>>> lines = ["cat 23\n", "dog 11\n"]
>>> "".join(lines).split()
['cat', '23', 'dog', '11']
>>> data = iter("".join(lines).split())
>>> [(next(data), next(data)) for i in range(2)]
[('cat', '23'), ('dog', '11')]
```

However if I change lines to be equals to:

```
lines = ["cat 23\n"]
```

I get a StopIteration with no list produced.

EDIT:
As with the responses below, the answer was because I was using 2 instead of 1. is there a way to get the length of an iterator without consuming it?

Comment: Because you specified two pairs with range(2).

Comment: count how many items you have each time

Comment: Thank you :) took me a while to get it so how could I replace that number with a value such as len? i will edit my question to reflect the change required

Comment: @Har Use the length of the list divided by two because they are pairs. And if my answer helped, please mark as answer.

Comment: The problem is that I have an iterator and not a list and therefore it will be consumed

Comment: Can't you cast it to a list?

Comment: yes but is there an alternate way of doing this on the fly in the expression itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified two pairs when iterating when it should be one to reflect your list of lines:

```
size = len("".join(lines).split()) # size of list
[(next(data), next(data)) for i in range(size / 2)]
```

Comment: Could you please update the answer to include the length information of each pair?

Answer (score 1):

That list comprehension is basically:

```
l = list()
l.append((next(data), next(data)))
l.append((next(data), next(data)))
```

You are calling `next(data)` four times on an iterator that evidently gives only two elements.